# How to output treatment for predicted CATE using CausalForest using DoWhy in python?

Tags: python, causality, causalimpact

I am new to Causal Inference but working on my first project. In this project I have a continuous treatment such as `discount%`.  My outcome or Y is the `purchase_amount`. Thus, I defined my vars as:

```
y = purchase_amount
T = discount% (0,5,10)
X = some covariates
W = some confounders
```

I found an article (https://towardsdatascience.com/causal-machine-learning-for-econometrics-causal-forests-5ab3aec825a7) which uses CausalForest to estimate CATE for a given treatment on a user basis. However, when I run the model, I get output such as:

```
User_id | CATE
1       | -0.2
2       |  0.21
..
```

Given this code snippet:

```
from econml.dml import CausalForestDML
from sklearn.linear_model import MultiTaskLassoCV

    # set parameters for causal forest 
    causal_forest = CausalForestDML(criterion='het', 
                                    n_estimators=10000,       
                                    min_samples_leaf=10, 
                                    max_depth=None, 
                                    max_samples=0.5,
                                    discrete_treatment=False,
                                    honest=True,
                                    inference=True,
                                    cv=10,
                                    model_t=MultiTaskLassoCV(), 
                                    model_y=MultiTaskLassoCV(),
                                    )
                          
    # fit train data to causal forest model 
    causal_forest.fit(Y, T, X=X, W=W)
    # estimate the CATE with the test set 
    causal_forest.const_marginal_ate(X_test)
```

Given my output above, how do I know for which treatment value these CATEs are? For example, if we have 3 discounts (0%, 5%, 10%) and I predict a user's CATE of -0.2, does that apply for 0%, 5%, or 10%? It is not clear to me how I can identify this. I hope someone can help.

Comment: For a better understanding of your situation, could you provide (parts of) the matrices `X`, `T`, `X_test`, and also (part of) the output of the call to `const_marginal_ate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, the model `CausalForestDML` presumes that the outcome `Y` depends [linearly](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/spec/estimation/dml.html#overview-of-formal-methodology) on the treatment `T`. That means this relation is independent of the treatment `T`. The proportionality factor $\theta(\mathbf X)$ (the "effect") depends solely on the feature covariates $\mathbf X$. Thus, it is the same for all your three discounts (0%, 5%, 10%).

**Second**, in your code you ask for the [`const_marginal_ate()`](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/_autosummary/econml.dml.CausalForestDML.html#econml.dml.CausalForestDML.const_marginal_ate), which is $E_{\mathbf X}[\theta(\mathbf X)]$, i.e. it is the average over all possible feature covariates $\mathbf X$ and thus doesn't even depend on $\mathbf X$ anymore.

**Third**, in this model, you can have multiple treatments $\mathbf T$, and multiple outcomes $\mathbf Y$, and for each treatment-outcome pair, you can compute the constant marginal ATE. Thus, you have a *matrix* of effects. But from your post, I could not figure out whether this is the case in your situation. It seems like you have just one treatment variable `discount%`, which can take on three possible values (0%, 5%, 10%), and only one outcome variable `purchase_amount`, in which case the return type of `const_marginal_ate()` should be a scalar, see the part `Returns` in the [documentation](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/_autosummary/econml.dml.CausalForestDML.html#econml.dml.CausalForestDML.const_marginal_ate).

I am also not sure about your posted output table: on the one hand, you say you compute the constant marginal ATE (because you use `const_marginal_ate()`), but on the other hand the column header in your posted output table is `CATE`. And maybe the column header `User_id` is your covariate `W`, but this is also not clear.

**Summary**: In general, for `d_y` outcomes `Y` and `d_t` treatments `T`, the result of `const_marginal_ate()` is a `d_y x d_t` matrix $M$, constant in the particular values of the treatments and of the covariates `X`, which gives in each cell $M_{ij}$ the effect of the $j$-th treatment on the $i$-th outcome.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. it makes all sense. I guess the last confirmation is how to read the output of such treatment-outcome pair for each user? Is that something like "for 1 unit of increase in Treatment 1 (discount=5%), we see an avg change in Y of something"? or for 1 unit of increase in Treatment 2 (discount=0%), we see an avg change in Y of something...etc. Is that the normal way of reading outputs from such models?

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, you have just one treatment, the discount, which can take on three values 0, 5, and 10. You would have more than one treatment if you would e.g. not only treat them with a discount but also in some other way, e.g. send them flowers (second treatment) and buy them a new car (third treatment).